# CKEditor 5 : How to access raw text in Angular application

Tags: angular, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am using CKEditor 5 in my Angular application. I have to check that the text entered by the user in the editor has at least 100 characters. The problem is that the model bound to the editor receives the text + the html markup created by the editor for formatting. So I want somehow to bind a second property of my model to the raw text of the editor. Is this possible ?

In my component, I can access the editor like this :

```
 @ViewChild('ckeditor', { static: true }) private _ckEditor: CKEditorComponent;
```

I have tried this as a test but I can't find the raw text:

```
  onBlur() {
   console.log( this._ckEditor.editorInstance.document.getBody().getText());
  }
```

and the html :

```
<ckeditor #ckeditor id="desc" name="desc" [editor]="editor" (blur)="onBlur()"
                [(ngModel)]="mymodel"></ckeditor>
```

Comment: I don't know much about the ckeditor5. could you provide a stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

CK Editor 5 now provides Word Count Plugin which can be used to count words and characters entered in editor.

[image]

Documentation link : https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/word-count.html

Comment: While this might answer the question, if possible you should [edit] your answer to include the most important information from the documentation provided in the answer itself. This can help prevent your answer from becoming invalid if the link stops working or the content significantly changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can add selector to ckeditor element (e.g. #myckeditor)

In ts file:

```
@ViewChild('myckeditor') myckeditor: CKEditor5.Editor;
```

And then get only plain text:

```
this.myckeditor.elementRef.nativeElement.innerText;
```